# How to get alert in series in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Could you please tell me how How to get alert in series in javascript .
I want expected output  when I click on middle box “yellow” box it gives alert in this series
**“bHandler” — > “cHandler” —>”aHandler”**
I already know bubbling and capturing in javascript

Here is my code
https://jsbin.com/vijobudafi/edit?html,css,js,output

```
function aHandler(){
  alert('aHandler');
}

function bHandler(){
  alert('bHandler');
}

function cHandler(){
  alert('cHandler');
}

document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("click", aHandler);
document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", bHandler,{capture: true});
document.getElementById("c").addEventListener("click", cHandler);
```

I add capturing in `b div`

Comment: Attach B handler to element A.

Comment: DO you want the alert to be a -> b -> c every time

Comment: _“I already know bubbling and capturing in javascript”_ - do you though? You are getting the alerts in this order, _because_ you decided to handle the click on b in the capturing and not the bubbling phase … So I don’t know what answer you expect here now, other than if you don’t _want_ that, then don’t _do_ that?

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] **in the question itself**. Your HTML is missing. There shouldn't be any need to link to JS Bin, Stackoverflow supports [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Post also your HTML.

Comment: How about a anonymous function `function () { aHandler(); bHandler(); cHandler(); }`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `onclick` inline?

example: https://jsfiddle.net/6n2opf5L/

```
  <div class="a" id="a">
    <div class="b" id="b" onclick="bHandler(); cHandler(); aHandler();">
      <div class="c" id="c"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This way you can tell in what order to open by placing them inside `onclick=""`

I hope this helps!